# c# smtp get cookies

Tags: c#, .net

How I can get cookies in smtp?

My code

```
SmtpClient Smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru", 2525);
Smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(dom_[0], dom[1]);
//Smtp.EnableSsl = false;

//Формирование письма
MailMessage Message = new MailMessage();
Message.IsBodyHtml = true;
Message.From = new MailAddress(dom[0]);
Message.To.Add(new MailAddress(mail));
Message.Subject = ch[0];
Message.Body = ch[1];


Smtp.Send(Message);//отправка
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't.

Cookies are an HTTP concept, not a SMTP concept.

Answer (score 1):

You get cookie values from the ASP.NET page or user control you are calling this code from, and pass them into the mail message.  The mail message itself doesn't support cookies, but the page or user control calling it does.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to do this by referencing an external resource ( an image for example ) but this will only make sense if the user opens the email in a browser and even then it might still be blocked by the browser or the browser email client.
Ether way i think it's a bad idea to try setting cookies from emails.